# error while installing autopsy

Tags: macos, terminal, mac, java

I tried to install Autopsy on my Mac by following "https://slo-sleuth.github.io/tools/InstallingAutopsyOnMacOS.html#installation-overview". After I wrote

"% cd ~/Downloads/autopsy-4.16.0
% sh unix_setup.sh"
I receive an error "ERROR: sleuthkit-4.10.2.jar not found in /usr/share/java/ or /usr/local/share/java/.
Please install the Sleuth Kit Java bindings file."

and I already installed sleuthkit-4.10.2

Answer (score 1):

Based on [the script itself](https://github.com/sleuthkit/autopsy/blob/32eb2bc13d175bd33f0291e1785b3457b571b066/unix_setup.sh#L43) and the information on the FAQ, I would guess that you did not install Sleuthkit with Java support. Review [this installation step](https://slo-sleuth.github.io/tools/InstallingAutopsyOnMacOS.html#building-the-sleuthkit) and then verify that you do have it installed by following the [Troubleshooting](https://slo-sleuth.github.io/tools/InstallingAutopsyOnMacOS.html#troubleshooting) step that checks for the required jar file.

Comment: I reinstalled many times,, what is the best Version with autopsy-4.18.0 , is it Sleuthkit-4.10.0 or Sleuthkit-4.10.2 ?

Comment: Since it was released at the same time, I would suggest trying Sleuthkit-4.10.2.  However, getting back to your issue, can you confirm that the jar file was created? What do you get when you run "ls /usr/local/share/java/sleuthkit*"